# F# lambda expression with multiple statements

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# and finding I'm writing things that work but which I don't entirely understand. Here's an example

```
let processArgs args =
    match args with
    | null
    | [||]          -> [fun() -> getCredentials(); home 20; mentions 20; messages 20]
    | [|"-h"|] 
    | [|"-?"|]      -> [showHelp]
    | [|"-reset"|]  -> [clearAllSettings]
    | _             -> [fun() -> printfn "%s" (String.Join(" ", args))]

[<EntryPoint>]
    let main (args:string[]) =
    try
        let actions = processArgs args
        List.iter (fun action -> action()) actions
        0
    finally
        Console.ResetColor()
        Console.CursorVisible <- true
```

The methods getCredentials, home, mentions, messages, showHelp, and clearAllSettings are all simple functions and do what you expect. (Yes, it's a twitter client, isn't that the new 'Hello World' demo?)

The line:

```
[fun() -> getCredentials(); home 20; mentions 20; messages 20]
```

works like I want. It calls getCredentials, then home, then mentions, then messages

From my perspective, the semicolon is acting like a statement separator. I haven't seen this described before. Is that what is going on here?

Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this (in other words, would a seasoned F# programmer roll on the floor laughing when he/she saw this)?

Further information: My original intent was to have a list of actions and then add actions as I discover options. In C# I would typically do this with List< Action >(). The semicolon thing surprised me because originally I tried to write it like:

```
[getCredentials; home 20; mentions 20; messages 20]
```

But the compiler didn't like it.

Comment: Well, a few hours of digging around the the language specification reveals the answer. It's a form of the syntax known as verbose syntax. Here's a link describing it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx I'm still wondering if my approach to parsing command line arguments is how F#'ers would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
[fun() -> getCredentials(); home 20; mentions 20; messages 20]
```

the compiler creates a list with only one element which is a function of type `unit -> unit`. `S1 ; S2` is sequence composition when S1 has type of `unit`, and S1 and S2 are executed in order and S2's result is returned. Therefore, three functions `home`, `mentions` and `messages` actually have the signature `int -> unit`.

If you want to create a list of 4 different functions, it should be:

```
[ getCredentials; // ; is optional
  fun () -> home 20; 
  fun () -> mentions 20; 
  fun () -> messages 20 ]
```

These functions are separated by whitespace to avoid confusion of using ; as list delimiter and sequence composition.

Since your example has all lists with only one elements, it could be simplified a lot:

```
let processArgs = function
    | [||]          -> getCredentials(); home 20; mentions 20; messages 20
    | [|"-h"|] 
    | [|"-?"|]      -> showHelp()
    | [|"-reset"|]  -> clearAllSettings()
    | args          -> printfn "%s" (String.Join(" ", args))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args:string[]) =
  try
    processArgs args
    0
  finally
    Console.ResetColor()
    Console.CursorVisible <- true
```

Comment: You're correct sir. My C# idioms keep getting in the way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Bernadette, it has been fixed.

Comment: But if the compiler creates a list with only one element from this, wouldn't all the pattern branches have to return a list ?